# Batch processing of Tiff files using skimage (Python)

Tags: python, image, batch-processing, tiff, scikit-image

I am looking to; open, process and save multiple TIFFs in Python.

I have the following code to open, process and save 1 (one) TIFF, but I have trouble with multiple files:

```
import skimage.io
import skimage.viewer
import skimage                 
import skimage.io    
         
# Read 1 image.TIF:
image = skimage.io.imread(fname=path)
image[2,1]= 1.0

# Process the file (make binary)
gray_image = skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)

# Blur the image to denoise (larger sigma = more noise removed)
blurred_image = skimage.filters.gaussian(gray_image, sigma=5)

# Adding threshold, t:
t = 0.8
binary_mask = blurred_image < t

# Save the file to another location:
skimage.io.imsave(fname=path, arr = binary_mask)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That code won't run. You've forgotten to define *path*

Comment: I know :-) the path is just any TIF file. The path would be different from my original code to the code, I am looking for (as it would need to read multiple files in one folder).

Comment: Multiprocessing would be ideal for this. Is that something you've considered?

Comment: I am new to Python, so I don't know the best method of batch-processing. But I will look into it, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a multiprocessing approach that may help:

```
import skimage
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from glob import glob
import os.path

source_dir = '<your source directory>'
target_dir = '<your target directory>'
filetype = '*.tif'

def process(path):
    image = skimage.io.imread(fname=path)
    image[2,1] = 1.0
    gray_image = skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)
    blurred_image = skimage.filters.gaussian(gray_image, sigma=5)
    outpath = os.path.join(target_dir, os.path.basename(path))
    arr = blurred_image < 0.8
    skimage.io.imsave(fname=outpath, arr=arr)

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        filelist = glob(os.path.join(source_dir, filetype))
        executor.map(process, filelist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Use *glob* to identify all the files matching the *.tif pattern then utilise the ProcessPoolExecutor's *map* function to process each file in its own process. As the processing is mainly CPU intensive, multiprocessing is likely to be the best fit for this

Comment: Thank you. When I am running this code, I get the error: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'process' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>. I am trying to look at limitation with multiprocessing. Have you experienced this error before?

Comment: @Fred If you're getting that error then you haven't copied the code in my answer

Comment: I have copied the exact code and when running selected code (selecting all), I get the error-code. If I run the code normally, nothing happens.

Comment: @Fred Did you add your source and target directories? Maybe update your question with the code you're now using based on this answer

Comment: Yes. I have added the source directory as the folder, where my original TIFFs are located. The target directory is the folder, the processed TIFFs should be saved. Like this: source_dir = r'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\folder'

Comment: @Fred Please update your question with the **exact** code you're using. I can assure you this code works. Bear in mind that if no files matching the pattern exist in the specified source directory, nothing will happen. Some TIFF files use the extension .tiff. If that's the case on your system then just change the *filetype* pattern to '\*.tif\*'

Answer (score -1):

Is it necessary that this be parallelized? It's not a huge bit of processing that you are performing. If you don't need parallel processing you can just run a for loop on your images

```
import skimage.io
import skimage.viewer
import skimage                 
import skimage.io
import os
import glob

# set up an in and out directory
in_dir = 'directory\with\images'
out_ir = 'directory\for\procecessed\images'

# make a list of all of the raw image files
os.chdir(in_dir)
filelist = glob.glob('*.png') # change to whatever file pattern you need here


for file_iter in filelist:
        
    os.chdir(in_dir)
    image = skimage.io.imread(fname=file_iter)
    image[2,1]= 1.0

    # Process the file (make binary)
    gray_image = skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)

    # Blur the image to denoise (larger sigma = more noise removed)
    blurred_image = skimage.filters.gaussian(gray_image, sigma=5)

    # Adding threshold, t:
    t = 0.8
    binary_mask = blurred_image < t

    # Save the file to another location:
    out_filename = file_iter[:-4] + 'processed.png' # make new filename based on old filename
    os.chdir(out_dir)
    skimage.io.imsave(fname=out_filename, arr = binary_mask)
```

Comment: Why chdir()? That's just a waste of time. Why not multiprocess? How do you know how many files there are to be processed?

Comment: @ArthurKing I was just trying to offer an alternative approach being that the OP seemed to be having trouble with the parallel processing on their end. You are absolutely correct that multiprocessing is going to be a much faster approach. I was unclear if this was a large enough data set to merit such a sophisticated approach.